# Variables Standarization

Tags: r, standardization

I have a data.frame with a total of 114 variables in columns. I should standardize them by using the `scale()` function in `R` but there is something that puzzles me:

Some of those variables, 10 of them, are variables that are indeed calculated as the z-score of other variables, which consists of a way of standardizing these variables as well. The question is, should I standardize all the variables, without taking it into consideration? Would those variables represent something like redundancy if applying a standardization to the other variables? Should I discard them as they would become meaningless? Should I include them but without applying the `scale()` function to them?

To be more precise:

Those z-score variables (and corresponding Pvalues which are other derived variables from those), are obtained such as:

From a native variable, say, with value -40, which is a free energy folding value obtained from folding an RNA sequence, I run a permutation over these RNA sequence to shuffle it and generate 100 RNA sequences, from which I calculate the corresponding free energy folding, get the mean and sd, and apply it to the original free energy value, so that, say mean = -30, sd = 5, I, and getting the z-score would be:

mean - value / sd >>>> -30 - (-40) / 5.

Z-score = 2

Should I standardize those values as well? or as they represent a standardize value from -40 original value, it is not necessary, and/or redundant?

Comment: You often don't need to standardize variables, depending on what you're trying to accomplish. Please provide more information about how you will use the data (standardized or not) in downstream applications.

Comment: I am computing variables from RNA sequences in order to implement a Classification Machine Learning algorithm based on training, test subsets. These variables have variable ranges so that to eliminate dispersion and avoid extreme outliers, I should perform some kind of normalisation, say, standarisation.